# Intercept every view element being inflated?

Tags: java, android, view, kotlin, layout-inflater

I am trying to intercept every view widget that is being inflated in my activity and override the setText functionality of that view if it exists.

So if a TextView has a android:text="bla" in the XML layout i want to be able to intercept that and maybe add a ** at the end of all texts being set from the xml.

One way that seems to be close to what i need is to use a Custom Layout inflator.

```
 LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(layoutInflator, InflatorOnSteriods(this))
```

and the in my InflatorOnSteriods to override onCreateView and then intercept all views there.. this approach doesn't seem to work at all. onCreateView is never called.

I tried also to use cloneInContext

```
 LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(layoutInflater.cloneInContext(this), InflatorOnSteriods(this))
```

But no luck as well, maybe my approach is totally wrong i am also open to a different way where i can intercept all views being presented and to be specific set a certain attribute on that view. It is really important to make sure that i will be the last one changing that view and make sure the system respects my changes and wont override them later.

**Update:**

*Although i don't think its relevant; Code of InflatorOnSteroids.kt*

```
class InflatorOnSteriods(val appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity) : LayoutInflaterFactory {

override fun onCreateView(parent: View, name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View {
    var result: View

    if (TextUtils.equals(name, "DebugDrawerLayout")) {
        result = ImageView(context, attrs)
    }
    result = appCompatActivity.onCreateView(name, context, attrs)
    if (result == null) {
        // Get themed views from app compat
        result = appCompatActivity.delegate.createView(parent, name, context, attrs)
    }
    return result
}
}
```

Comment: can you add the `InflatorOnSteriods` class code to your question?

Comment: I added the code @petey although the class now does nothing there ... so i dont think its the problem.. and my question is more of is that even the right approach, cause it might not be.

Comment: "So if a TextView has a android:text="bla" in the XML layout i want to be able to intercept that and maybe add a ** at the end of all texts being set from the xml." where is this occuring? (Also, its great you are using kotlin)

Comment: @petey what else would you use ;) lol.
What you mean where is this occurring ? My plan is to make sure i have a hook point wer i can intercept every single view that contains text attribute and then manipulate that text. Let me know if i need to clarify this a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time troubleshooting my solution i finally managed to achieve what i wanted with the inflator factory solution.

First i create an abstract activity that has a custom inflator set to it.

```
abstract class SteroidsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var mInflater: LayoutInflater? = null
abstract fun getActivityLayout(): Int

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mInflater = layoutInflater?.cloneInContext(this)
    LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(mInflater, InflaterOnSteroids(this))
    setContentView(getActivityLayout())
}

override fun getLayoutInflater(): LayoutInflater? {
    return mInflater
}

override fun getSystemService(name: String): Any? {
    if (name == LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) {
        if (mInflater == null) {
            mInflater = super.getSystemService(name) as LayoutInflater
        }
        return mInflater
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name)
  }
}
```

Second thing that you need to do is create your custom inflator factory

```
class InflaterOnSteroids(appCompatActivity1: AppCompatActivity) : LayoutInflaterFactory {

    override fun onCreateView(parent: View?, name: String, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View? {
      //Do stuff here and return a view
        return null
       }
 }
```

The problem with my code was that it was always crashing with a weird error that i couldn't troubleshoot until i realised that i need to add a **?** after View since i'm using kotlin and parent view can be null :)

Happy programming

Good reference can be found [here](http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/layoutinflater-factories/)